# Javascript: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, timer

My code does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
function christmas(){
      var today = new Date();
      var day = today.getDate();
      var month = today.getMonth()+1;
      if(day>=0 && month=12){
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "files/snowstorm.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Learn how to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  "It doesn't work" is _not_ a problem statement.  A problem statement clearly defines the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing assignment in a conditional `if(day>=0 && month=12)`. `month === 12` instead of `month=12`.

Comment: This is an opportunity to teach.  Don't just provide an answer (albeit correct) - teach something - debugging, how to ask a question, something.  OP clearly could use input / advice on how to use console, debugging, at least on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I agree and I usually go back and edit my answers after I post the short & sweet version. I've learned that when I write detailed answers they've already accepted someone else's with the same answer that just gets the job done.

Comment: There should be no answer at all, this is just a typo so can be closed off topic because it's "*…caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*"